# Fetching Google Map tile without using Google Maps API

Tags: software-recommendations, google-maps-api

Is there any  way to fetch Google map tiles without using the Google Maps API?

Microsoft Bing Map provides a REST API.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot directly access the tiles without circumventing the T&C of Google's API.

If you want the map as an image you can do that with Google Maps Static API.